# Python equivalent to Objective-C categories or extending JavaScript prototype?

Tags: python, prototype, extend, objective-c-category

I'd like to add functionality to the `set` data type of Python. In Objective-C I might use a category like so:

```
@implementation Set (CirrostratusAdditions)
- (Set *)modifiedSet;{return self;}
@end
```

Or in JavaScript like so:

```
Set.prototype.modifiedSet = function(){};
```

Is it possible to append functionality to existing classes in Python. If so, what is this concept called within Python runtime and where might I best get acquainted with the concept?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Python, and you probably shouldn't; it's not very Pythonic.

What you can do, however, is extend the bulitin type and add methods to that.